# Attempt To dereference null object for != in if and no error for == in if

Tags: apex, string, null-pointer

I have been trying to use this code:

```
system.debug('aaaa'+o.Registration_No__c);
if(o.Registration_No__c !=null || o.Registration_No__c.trim() !='')
{
    bFirst.RegisterNo   = o.Registration_No__c ;
}
```

Registration_No__c is a text field.
o.Registration_No__c from debug returns a value. But if I use the above code I get Attempt to dereference a null object error on the line with if condition.
So, I changed the code to:

```
system.debug('aaaa'+o.Registration_No__c);
if(o.Registration_No__c ==null || o.Registration_No__c.trim() =='')
{
}
else
{                                      
    bFirst.RegisterNo   = o.Registration_No__c ;
}
```

and it works just fine.
I dont understand what the problem was?

Comment: In the first one when your value is `null`, since you are using `||` operator, it's trying to evaluate the second part of the if clause. There it tries to perform `trim()` on null instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have an or condition, you evaluate the first condition, and if it is true, you return, otherwise, you evaluate the next condition. So when you have

```
someString != null || someString.trim() != ''
```

it will only evaluate `someString.trim()` if `someString` *is equal to* `null`. **You want to use `&&` instead of `||` in your initial logic.**

Consider also proper logical negation. In addition to flipping equality operators, you need to swap `and` with `or`. `!(a || b)` is equivalent to `!a && !b`.

Consider also that there is a `String` [method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) named `isNotBlank`.

> Returns true if the specified String is not whitespace, not empty (''), and not null; otherwise, returns false.

So you are actually **reinventing the wheel** anyway. Just use:

```
String.isNotBlank(o.Registration_No__c)
```